# Washing machine leak has caused floor and cupboard damage, is it repairable or do I need to purchase new parts to fix?

Tags: wood, leak, vinyl-flooring

Unfortunately my washing machine had a small leak in it and has caused some minor damage on my Amtico Spacia flooring and the wood panel that separates the unit into two spaces.

The flooring is waterproof, but the adhesive is not, I am reading conflicting advise online where some times state the whole panel needs to be removed and others where it indicates I just need clean off the old adhesive and then reapply new adhesive to fix the flooring. What would be the best course of action here, to simply purchase new adhesive or get a new panel of vinyl and adhesive?

[image: Lifted flooring]

For the wood panel, it appears the water has absorbed from the bottom of the floor into the board and started to swell which has caused it to split at the edges slightly. I was hoping that while the wood is still damp, I would be able to clamp it down in hope that when it dries out it would go back to a more normal shape than what it currently is. Would that work with returning it back to normal, or is there another method available to me that would remedy the swelling?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the damage is done and quite irreversible. The wood fibers have swollen and broken the glue bond that held them together. You could certainly apply clamping pressure to the damaged board for a few weeks until the water dries out. The top layer of your floor is waterproof if installed correctly but the bottom appears to be wood and was warped by the water. You could re-wet it and put something heavy on it until it dries; this would give you the best odds of gluing it back down but don't expect perfection.

Comment: I don't think there is any wood on the bottom of the floor, it appears to be concrete but the way the adhesive is does make it appear as wood! Would applying a clamp to the swollen wood actually do anything, or do you think it would just revert back to it's current state once it had dried and the clamps removed?

Comment: First course of action, call your insurance company - it's their job to fix it ;)) [btw, swollen particle/chip board is a one-way ticket. The forces used to compress it like that when you buy it will not be matched by anything you own or can easily buy.]

Comment: @Tetsujin "First course of action, call your insurance company" - with utmost respect, LOL that is terrible advice. The rest of your comment about industrial compressive forces, spot on =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - upon what basis do you dismiss my advice? Background for mine: both myself & my mother worked in insurance for many years (probably 25, between us). This was not 'guesswork'. Why pay for insurance & never use it? That's what it's for.

Comment: @Tetsujin In the US it is not wise to file frivolous claims. https://www.thezebra.com/homeowners-insurance/guide/when-to-file-homeowners-insurance-claim/

Comment: I don't file insurance claims for less than 20k.  I can't imagine filing for insurance on this kind of damage.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - I wouldn't define that as frivolous. it's going to cost more than excess, it's unlikely to be repeated. Most companies these days would apply a lien rather than a premium increase, so you're still fully covered for everything, but if you have the same claim type again within *x* years, your excess for that will be considerably higher. [This is partly to ensure you fix it properly in the first place.]

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - then you're just spending money you don't have to. That's a fool's game. You paid for insurance; learn when to use it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have filed insurance claims for two floods both at the 15-20k range.  Not worth the hassle.  I could hire better people who do things quicker at higher quality for 1/2 the cost of what the insurance company pays.  So a 20k insurance claim is really less than 10k of value - top that off you loose the 5/10 year no claim discounts and you pay a deductible.  So the 10k value minus 5k but instead of 1-2 months to finish it is 6 months.  I go for maximum deductible on my policies - I'll use insurance for catastrophic loss.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - Insurance company gives you money, after an assessment. Money buys tradesmen. Insurance companies will always try to fob you off with 'their guys' but you don't have to use them. I've known assessors try to give 'vouchers' for certain stores. They're working you for a back-hander [assessors are hired by the Ins Co, they're not employees]. If you can get it fixed to your satisfaction for 10, you just pocketed 10 grand.

Comment: btw, it always helps if you know their 'buzzwords' for things. Hit the right terminology & they bend like the reed. Use the wrong terms & they're rigid. It's not 'flood damage' or 'a water leak' it's '*storm damage*', so long as there was an acknowledged storm on the date of your claim. That sets you up on the right track from the get go, you ticked all the right boxes. [I'm using UK terminology, it's wise to look up the precise equivalent in your territory]. If you know how they work, you can get them to work for you, rather than fight you every step of the way.